# В чем ошибка в игре на питоне?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import pygame
import os

APP_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
os.chdir(APP_DIR)

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,480))

pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")

walkRight = [pygame.image.load('Cowboy/walk_0.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Cowboy/walk_1.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Cowboy/walk_2.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Cowboy/walk_3.png')]
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('Cowboy/Lwalk_0.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Cowboy/Lwalk_1.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Cowboy/Lwalk_2.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Cowboy/Lwalk_3.png')]
bg = pygame.image.load('Cowboy/background.png')
char = [pygame.image.load('Cowboy/idle_0.png'),
pygame.image.load('Cowboy/idle_1.png'),
pygame.image.load('Cowboy/idle_2.png'),
pygame.image.load('Cowboy/idle_3.png')]

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#bulletSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('bullet.wav')
#hitSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('hit.wav')

music = pygame.mixer.music.load('country.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

score = 0

class player(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 5
        self.isJump = False
        self.left = False
        self.right = False
        self.walkCount = 0
        self.jumpCount = 10
        self.standing = True
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 11, 29, 52)

    def draw(self, win):
        if self.walkCount + 1 >= 27:
            self.walkCount = 0

        if not(self.standing):
            if self.left:
                win.blit(walkLeft[self.walkCount//3], (self.x,self.y))
                self.walkCount += 1
            elif self.right:
                win.blit(walkRight[self.walkCount//3], (self.x,self.y))
                self.walkCount +=1
        else:
            if self.right:
                win.blit(walkRight[0], (self.x, self.y))
            else:
                win.blit(walkLeft[0], (self.x, self.y))
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 11, 29, 52)
        #pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,0,0), self.hitbox,2)

    def hit(self):
        self.isJump = False
        self.jumpCount = 10
        self.x = 100
        self.y = 410
        self.walkCount = 0
        font1 = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 100)
        text = font1.render('-5', 1, (255,0,0))
        win.blit(text, (250 - (text.get_width()/2),200))
        pygame.display.update()
        i = 0
        while i < 200:
            pygame.time.delay(10)
            i += 1
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    i = 201
                    pygame.quit()


                
class projectile(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,radius,color,facing):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.facing = facing
        self.vel = 8 * facing

    def draw(self,win):
        pygame.draw.circle(win, self.color, (self.x,self.y), self.radius)


class enemy(object):
    walkRight = [pygame.image.load('Cowboy/R_walk_0.png')]
    walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('Cowboy/L_walk_0.png')]

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, end):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.end = end
        self.path = [self.x, self.end]
        self.walkCount = 0
        self.vel = 3
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 2, 31, 57)
        self.health = 10
        self.visible = True

    def draw(self,win):
        self.move()
        if self.visible:
            if self.walkCount + 1 >= 33:
                self.walkCount = 0

            if self.vel > 0:
                win.blit(self.walkRight[self.walkCount //3], (self.x, self.y))
                self.walkCount += 1
            else:
                win.blit(self.walkLeft[self.walkCount //3], (self.x, self.y))
                self.walkCount += 1

            pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,0,0), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 20, 50, 10))
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (0,128,0), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 20, 50 - (5 * (10 - self.health)), 10))
            self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 2, 31, 57)
            #pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,0,0), self.hitbox,2)

    def move(self):
        if self.vel > 0:
            if self.x + self.vel < self.path[1]:
                self.x += self.vel
            else:
                self.vel = self.vel * -1
                self.walkCount = 0
        else:
            if self.x - self.vel > self.path[0]:
                self.x += self.vel
            else:
                self.vel = self.vel * -1
                self.walkCount = 0

    def hit(self):
        if self.health > 0:
            self.health -= 1
        else:
            self.visible = False
        print('hit')


def redrawGameWindow():
    win.blit(bg, (0,0))
    text = font.render('Score: ' + str(score), 1, (0,0,0))
    win.blit(text, (350, 10))
    man.draw(win)
    goblin.draw(win)
    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw(win)
    
    pygame.display.update()


#mainloop
font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 30, True)
man = player(200, 410, 64,64)
goblin = enemy(100, 410, 64, 64, 450)
shootLoop = 0
bullets = []
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(27)

    if goblin.visible == True:
        if man.hitbox[1] < goblin.hitbox[1] + goblin.hitbox[3] and man.hitbox[1] + man.hitbox[3] > goblin.hitbox[1]:
            if man.hitbox[0] + man.hitbox[2] > goblin.hitbox[0] and man.hitbox[0] < goblin.hitbox[0] + goblin.hitbox[2]:
                man.hit()
                score -= 5

    if shootLoop > 0:
        shootLoop += 1
    if shootLoop > 3:
        shootLoop = 0
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        
    for bullet in bullets:
        if bullet.y - bullet.radius < goblin.hitbox[1] + goblin.hitbox[3] and bullet.y + bullet.radius > goblin.hitbox[1]:
            if bullet.x + bullet.radius > goblin.hitbox[0] and bullet.x - bullet.radius < goblin.hitbox[0] + goblin.hitbox[2]:
                hitSound.play()
                goblin.hit()
                score += 1
                bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
                
        if bullet.x < 500 and bullet.x > 0:
            bullet.x += bullet.vel
        else:
            bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and shootLoop == 0:
        bulletSound.play()
        if man.left:
            facing = -1
        else:
            facing = 1
            
        if len(bullets) < 5:
            bullets.append(projectile(round(man.x + man.width //2), round(man.y + man.height//2), 6, (0,0,0), facing))

        shootLoop = 1

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and man.x > man.vel:
        man.x -= man.vel
        man.left = True
        man.right = False
        man.standing = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and man.x < 500 - man.width - man.vel:
        man.x += man.vel
        man.right = True
        man.left = False
        man.standing = False
    else:
        man.standing = True
        man.walkCount = 0
        
    if not(man.isJump):
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            man.isJump = True
            man.right = False
            man.left = False
            man.walkCount = 0
    else:
        if man.jumpCount >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if man.jumpCount < 0:
                neg = -1
            man.y -= (man.jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
            man.jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            man.isJump = False
            man.jumpCount = 10
            
    redrawGameWindow()

pygame.quit()
```

Вот сама ошибка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Текст ошибки говорит, что вы вышли за пределы индекса в строке:

```
win.blit(self.walkRight[self.walkCount //3], (self.x, self.y))`
```

У вас в `self.walkRight` лишь одна картинка `walkRight = [pygame.image.load('Cowboy/R_walk_0.png')]` по индексу 0, поэтому доступ к любому другому индексу породит ошибку.